# Passing line breaks from SQL field to SSRS text box

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have an application that allows for line breaks in a text box. In this particular instance, I am passing an address to the database with line breaks. For example, within the application it is written as such:

```
Test Company Address
123 Address 1
City, State 55555
```

When I copy the field directly from SQL through SSMS, it is placing double spaces to signify that it is a line break. Example:

```
Test Company Address  123 Address 1  City, State 55555
```

How do I persist these line breaks to add it to a text box within SSRS? This way, when I bring in the field into SSRS it will recognize the double spaces and automatically line break for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried your scenario, SSRS **did** persist the line break. I didn't need to do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS will display any line breaks returned from the dataset.

SSMS replaces line breaks with 2 spaces in the "Results to Grid". If you switch the query to "Results to Text" you will be able to see the line breaks in the results for SSMS.